# How can I make `fun [x] -> x` exhaustive?

Tags: functional-programming, pattern-matching, ocaml

Say in Ocaml I have the following function:

```
let f = fun [x] -> x
```

I get the following warning as a result:

```
this pattern-matching is not exhaustive.
Here is an example of a value that is not matched:
[]
```

My goal is to create a function from `'a list -> 'a`. How can I account for `[]` being passed to that function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just have to decide what your function is supposed to do when the list has other than 1 element. jambono shows how to make the function fail in all such cases. Another fairly plausible function would always return the first element of the list and only fail if the list is empty. This function is known as `List.hd`.

```
let f = List.hd
```

Or you can implement it yourself:

```
let f = function
| [] -> failwith "empty list"
| x :: _ -> x
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to cover all possible cases. In addition to `[x]`, you can have an empty list and a list that contains more than one element:

```
let f = function 
    |[x] -> x
    | _ -> failwith "bad entry";;
```

`_`, the wildcard pattern, matches all possible values if `[x]` is not matched.

Comment: in the documentation they said, that function it is the same as fun for function that take more than 1 variable

Comment: (There's no room in comments to explain. You could ask as separate question on SO :-)

Comment: `function ...` is shorthand for `fun whatever -> match whatever with ...`